# Method with dynamic return value to get all rows from a specific table

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, data-access-layer

I have many of the following methods in my class for the data access:

```
public IEnmuerable<Customer> GetAllCustomer()
{
    return MyEFContext.tblCustomer;
}

public IEnmuerable<Company> GetAllCompanies()
{
    return MyEFContext.tblCompany;
}

public IEnmuerable<Car> GetAllCars()
{
    return MyEFContext.tblCar;
}

...
```

Is there a way to define a method with a dynamic return value that gives me all rows from a specific table. So that I can call something like this:

```
List<Customer> allCustomers = GetAll<Customer>().ToList();
```

I searched a lot but found nothing usefull. My last Code was this, but it also fails:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    return MyEFContext.Set<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After many try and errors, here comes my solution:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    return MyEFContext.Set(typeof(T)) as IEnumerable<T>;
}
```

Now I can call this method like:

```
List<Customer> allMyCustomers = GetAll<Customer>().ToList();
```